# :target selector doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my Markup:

```
<p>A paragraph with <a id="link" href="#link">a link</a> inside it.</p>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$("a:target").css("font-size","2em");
```

When I click on the link, the URL changes to `http://example.com/file.html#link`. However, the `font-size` does not increase. 
There is no change in `font-size` even if I directly load `http://example.com/file.html#link`

Why is the selector not working?

Update: I have to use the `:target` selector. There is no choice.

Comment: I don't see any targets with `id='link'` in that page. And note that the `:target` selector will select the ***target*** element and not the link which redirects to the target.

Comment: @Harry that's just an example page, not the actual one. Could you please elaborate what do you mean by "the `:target` selector will select the target element and not the link which redirects to the target".

Comment: When you put an `a` with `href='#link'`, the URL will look like `http://yoursite.com/#link` and it means that the link redirects to yoursite.com and target the element with `id='link'` in your page. It could be any element (a `p` or a `div` or anything). Lets say the element that has `id='link'` is a `p` then the `:target` selector will target that `p` element which is the current target.

Comment: This jQuery documentation page could help you too - https://api.jquery.com/target-selector/

Comment: Have your code in document ready or try it on other browser too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem that you used `:target` selector immediately after anchor clicking. When you click on anchor, javascript run your selector immediately while browser doesn't focus on target element. You need to pause your code for miliseconds then run `:target` selector.

```js
$("a").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("a:target").css("font-size","2em");
    }, 1); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    A paragraph with 
    <a id="link" href="#link">a link</a>
    inside it.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad. 

Why does the code not work when I directly load : http://example.com/file.html#link

Comment: @SanJeetSingh Because you adding css when mouse click.

Comment: No, I am not. I don't have a `click` function in my code. 

I just directly write `$("a:target").css("font-size","2em")` inside the script tag :)

Comment: Thanks for the demo @Mohammad but it sets the hash using `window.location.hash = "#link";`. When I load it using the URL https://jsfiddle.net/vydct0bn/1/#link it does not work. Why is that?

Comment: @SanJeetSingh Also you need to use `setTimeout` on page load to do this work. Run **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/vydct0bn/2/)** code in your local because you cant use `#link` in jsfiddle url.

Comment: I am checking it locally :). Could you please tell me why I need to use `setTimeout` in the second case?

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad it worked. Could you please tell me why I had to use `setTimeout` in second case?

Comment: @SanJeetSingh Because javascript code executed before browser focusing on element. You can test it. Write `alert()` in root of code then load page. `alert()` displayed befor going to element.